# How to evaluate $\int \frac{x^6}{x^4-1} \, \mathrm{d}x.$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, partial-fractions

Evaluate the integral:

$$\int \frac{x^6}{x^4-1} \, \mathrm{d}x$$

After a lot of help I have reached this point:

$x^2 = Ax^3 - Ax + Bx^2 - B + Cx^3 + Cx^2 + Cx + C + Dx^3 - Dx^2 + Dx - D$

But now I don't really know how to solve for $A, B, C$, and $D$. Please help!

Comment: First do division, then factor the denominator using difference of squares.

Answer (score 9):

First: Divide! Use polynomial division to get $$\frac{x^6}{x^4 - 1} = 1 + \frac{x^2}{x^4 - 1}$$ $\int 1\,dx = x + C$

For the second term:

Now factor the denominator, and decompose: $$x^4 - 1 = (x^2 + 1)(x^2-1) = (x^2 + 1)(x-1)(x+1)$$

So the set up we want for the second term is:

$$\frac{x^2}{x^4 - 1} = \dfrac{Ax + B}{x^2 + 1} +\frac{C}{x-1} + \frac D{x+1}$$

Now solve for A, B, C, D.

Comment: When I did the log division I got 1 + (x^2/x^4 - 1) o_o where did I go wrong?

Comment: You long division is correct.

Comment: Would I have to simplify it further like this?: x^2 = Ax+B(x-1)(x+1) + C (x^2+1)(x+1) + D (x^2 + 1)(x-1) and then distribute?

Comment: That would give me x^2 = Ax^3 - Ax + Bx^2 - B + Cx^3 + Cx^2 + Cx + C + Dx^3 - Dx^2 + Dx - D. Now what should I do to solve for A, B, C, and D? I don't really know how to do that.

Comment: @user152099 I don't understand what track you're on, but I think the idea here is to split $\frac{x^2}{x^4-1}$ into partial fractions. This is a common technique to solve these sorts of problems and is worth learning.

Comment: If a_nx^n + ... + a_0 = b_nx^n + ... + b_0, so, a_n = b_n, ..., a_0 = b_0.

Comment: @user152099 Go back to your line above. You can get started by solving that equation when $x = 1$. That will give you $C$.  Then do the same for $x = -1$: That will give you D.  Then using your values for $C, D$, let, say, $x = 0$. And if needed, set $x = 2$. Then you'll have two equations and two unknowns (A, B). Solve.

Comment: I can't find A, I set x = 2 but I got a fraction. :/

Comment: @user152099 Let me know how you're coming on solving for $A, B, C, D$.

Comment: You made a mistake.

Comment: @amWhy Your result from polynomial long division is incorrect. The $1$ out front by itself should be an $x^2$.

Answer (score 4):

Integrand can be transformed without long divison
$$\begin{gathered}\frac{x^6}{x^4 - 1}=\frac{x^6-1+1}{x^4 - 1}=\frac{(x^2-1)(x^4+x^2+1)}{x^4 - 1}+\frac{1}{x^4 - 1}=\\
=\frac{x^4+x^2+1}{x^2 + 1} + \frac{1}{x^4 - 1}=\\
=x^2+\frac{1}{x^2 + 1}+\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{x^2-1} - \frac{1}{x^2+1} \right)=\\
=x^2 + \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{x^2-1} + \frac{1}{x^2+1} \right).
\end{gathered}$$

Answer (score 3):

Rewrite the integrand as
\begin{align}
\frac{x^6}{x^4-1}&\stackrel{\color{red}{[1]}}=\color{darkgreen}{x^2}+\color{blue}{\frac{x^2}{x^4-1}}\\
&=\color{darkgreen}{x^2}+\color{blue}{\frac{x^2}{(x^2-1)(x^2+1)}}\\
&\stackrel{\color{red}{[2]}}=\color{darkgreen}{x^2}+\color{blue}{\frac{1}{2}\left(\color{black}{\frac{1}{x^2+1}}+\color{red}{\frac{1}{x^2-1}}\right)}\\
&=\color{darkgreen}{x^2}+\color{blue}{\frac{1}{2}\left(\color{black}{\frac{1}{x^2+1}}+\color{red}{\frac{1}{(x-1)(x+1)}}\right)}\\
&\stackrel{\color{red}{[3]}}=\color{darkgreen}{x^2}+\color{blue}{\frac{1}{2}\left(\color{black}{\frac{1}{x^2+1}}+\color{red}{\frac12\left[\frac1{x-1}-\frac1{x+1}\right]}\right)}\\
&=x^2+\color{red}{\underbrace{\color{black}{\frac{1}{2(x^2+1)}}}_{\color{blue}{\large \color{black}{\text{set}}\ x=\tan\theta}}}+\color{red}{\underbrace{\color{black}{\frac1{4(x-1)}}}_{\color{blue}{\large \color{black}{\text{set}}\ u=x-1}}}-\color{red}{\underbrace{\color{black}{\frac1{4(x+1)}}}_{\color{blue}{\large \color{black}{\text{set}}\ v=x+1}}}
\end{align}

---

**Notes :**

$\color{red}{[1]}\;\;\;$Polynomial long division

$\color{red}{[2]}\text{ and }\color{red}{[3]}\;\;\;$Partial fractions decomposition